# How to check if a value in a List exist (before get out of range)

Tags: c#, list

I have this list :

```
IList<Modulo> moduli = (from Modulo module in Moduli
                       select module).ToList();
```

and I cycle it with for (notice i=i+2) :

```
for(int i=0; i<moduli.Count; i=i+2)
{
}
```

now, I have to check if moduli[i+1] exist (so, the next element), else I'll get a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`.

How can I check it? Tried with :

```
if(moduli[i+1] != null) 
{
}
```

but it doesnt works!

Comment: To begin with, change the loop condition to `i<moduli.Count` (not `<=`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check it the same way as you check your loop condition:

```
if(i + 1 < moduli.Count) // it exists
```

Note the `<` instead of `<=`, which is a mistake in your original code.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
if (i + 1 < moduli.Count)
{
  var modulo = moduli[i+1]; // this is safe
}
```

this should not be true if your i+1 will cause an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

By the way, the reason this doesn't work:

```
if(moduli[i+1] != null)
```

is that the ArgumentOutOfRangeException will be thrown as soon as you made the check.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for(int i=0; i <= (moduli.Count - (moduli.Count % 2)); i=i+2)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq can do the work for you :)

```
IList<Modulo> moduli = Moduli.Where((item, index) => ((index % 2) == 0)).
                              ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
for(int i=0; i<moduli.Count - 2; i=i+2) { }
```

Comment: Then add an extra if(moduli[moduli.Length-1] != null)  { } outside the loop!  Why add extra if checks in the loop which slow down performance?